# plot a set of 3D data in different angles in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, 3d, geometry-surface

I have a formula that depends on theta and phi (spherical coordinates 0<=theta<=2*pi and 0<=phi<=pi). By inserting each engle, I obtained a quantity. Now I have a set of data for different angles and I need to plot the surface. My data is a 180*360 matrix, so I am not sure if I can use SURF or MESH or PLOT3. The figure should be a surface that include all data and the axes should be in terms of the quantity, not the quantity versus the angles. How can I plot such a surface?

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why you cannot use `mesh` or `surf` to plot such data.  Another option I tend to use is that of density plots.  You basically display the dependent variable (quantity) as an image and include the independent variables (angles) along the axis, much like you would with the aforementioned 3D plotting functions.  This can be done with `imagesc`.

Typically you would want your axes to be the dependent variables.  Could you elaborate more on this point?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments ephsmith. But imagesc didn't work on my data. My formuale determines velocity of wave in diferent angles. Now I have a 180*360 matrix that each element is a velocity in a specific direction. I want to plot these velocities(matrix)as a surface in 3D. How can I plot such a matrix in 3D? you suppose that I have different velocities in all the directions and I want to make a surface of them that is a specified by the endpoints of each vector in lenght of each velocity.

Comment: Can you derive a mathematical expression for the surface you desire.  I'm imagining that you need to calculate the magnitude of each vector from your matrix.  What is the domain of the surface your wish to plot--ie what variables are to be on the axes?  I have experience with data visualisation for many types of data / data dependence, but  I'm missing out on the actual formulas here.  Could you provide the expressions in some way?

Comment: Thera is not an explicit formulea for my surface. But for convenience, Suppose that we have a formula, for example        v=sin(theta)+cos(phi) [0<=theta<=2*pi and 0<=phi<=pi], so we have a 180*360 matrix of v that correspond to each degree in 3D. For plotting this matrix, can we use: v1=sin(theta)*cos(phi)*v, v2=sin(theta)*sin(phi)*v and v3=cos(theta)*v then surf(v1,v2,v3)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you have calculated a function `f(theta,phi)` and now you want to plot the surface containing all the points with the polar coordinated `(r,theta,phi)` where `r=f(theta,phi)`.

If this is what you want to do, the 2D version of such a plot is included in MATLAB under the name [`polar`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/polar.html). Unfortunately, as you pointed out, `polar3` on [MatlabCentral](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7656) is not the generalization you are looking for.

I have been able to plot a sphere with the following code, using constant `r=1`. You can give it a try with your function:

```
phi1=0:1/(3*pi):pi; %# this would be your 180 points
theta1=-pi:1/(3*pi):pi; % your 360 points
r=ones(numel(theta1),numel(phi1));
[phi,theta]=meshgrid(phi1,theta1);
x=r.*sin(theta).*cos(phi);
y=r.*sin(theta).*sin(phi);
z=r.*cos(theta);
tri=delaunay(x(:),y(:),z(:));
trisurf(tri,x,y,z);
```

From my tests it seems that `delaunay` also includes a lot of triangles which go through the volume of my sphere, so it seems this is not optimal. So maybe you can have a look at [`fill3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fill3.html) and construct the triangles it draws itself: as a first approximation, you could have the points `[x(n,m) x(n+1,m) x(n,m+1)]` combined into one triangle, and `[x(n+1,m) x(n+1,m+1) x(n+1,m+1)]` into another...?

Comment: Thanks Jonas. polar3 plots 3D data over a disc.but my figure should have a shape, for example, pseudo-sphere origin(0,0),because the radii are different. For each phi and theta, we have a specific radius. The general data makes such a pseudo-sphere surface. I don't know how to plot such a surface that is just a sungle matrix.

Comment: okay, so I understood your question correctly, but the function doesn't do what you want :-/. I guess you might have to hand-code it...

Comment: Any luck so far? If you find a solution, be sure to post it here ;-)

Comment: I used your instruction,
phi=0:pi/pi:2*pi; 
theta=0:pi/pi:2*pi;
[phi,theta]=meshgrid(phi,theta);
% v is a martix(180*360) with different values.
v1=v.*sin(theta).*cos(phi);
v2=r.*sin(theta).*sin(phi);
v3=r.*cos(theta); 
surf(v1,v2,v3); 

And I got a closed surface which I think is alright. Do you think that with considering these v1,v2 and v3 we have all the data in each degree?